# Virtualbox: Win 7 x64 Professional Guest too slow on Win 10 host

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Win 7 x64 Professional on a Win 10 Host and I note that it is slow on starting and once started it continues slow as well.

I have installed virtualbox extension pack as well as Guest additions.
Virtualbox version is 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.2).

Assigned resources assigned to guest and configuration are:

- Chipset PIX3
- Enable I/O APIC
- 4352MB of memory
- 1 CPU / Limit execution to 100%
- Enabled PAE/Nx
- Paravirtualization set to default
- Enabled VT-x/AMD-V
- Enabled pagination
- Video memory of 256MB (I have an AMD Radeon R9 M265X)
- Video acceleration 3D and 2D enabled

I know that keeping host and guest in the same hard drive affects the performance.

My host machine has 8GB RAM intel i7 4th generation. How can I accelerate it? And my machine has VT-x enabled in firmware.

Comment: Give it a second core. Windows7 does not run well on a single core device.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, it seens like adding a second core it go a little bit faster.